# Position variables name in axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels

I am looking for a code - probably inside {axis}[options] - that **automatically** puts the variable name (for example, *x*, and *y*) at the end of each axis. I am aware of the method to do this manually, which includes adding the position of the node, like in:

```
ylabel=$y$, y label style={at={(0,1)}},
xlabel=$x$, x label style={at={(1,0)}},
```

Because I tend to work with many graphs, I want to do this automatically. To facilitate the answer, I add a MWE with the above lines:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
ylabel=$y$,
y label style={at={(0.18,1.05)}},
xlabel=$x$,
x label style={at={(1.05,0.13)}},
ytick=\empty,
xtick=\empty]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new style `labels at axis tips` like this:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    labels at axis tips/.style 2 args={
        compat=1.12,
        xlabel=#1,
        x label style={
            at={(current axis.right of origin)},
            anchor=west
        },
        ylabel=#2,
        y label style={
            at={(current axis.above origin)},
            anchor=west
        },
    },
    labels at axis tips/.default={$x$}{$y$}
}
```

Then you can call `labels at axis tips` in your `axis` options without any arguments to place the default labels, or you can call `labels at axis tips={xlabel}{ylabel}` to use a different label text.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    labels at axis tips/.style 2 args={
        compat=1.12,
        xlabel=#1,
        x label style={
            at={(current axis.right of origin)},
            anchor=west
        },
        ylabel=#2,
        y label style={
            at={(current axis.above origin)},
            anchor=west
        },
    },
    labels at axis tips/.default={$x$}{$y$}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
labels at axis tips,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
ytick=\empty,
xtick=\empty]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the trick! I changed the orientation of the y-axis, using `anchor=south,rotate=-90`. Surprisingly, that code doesn't work in 1.13. Any idea why?

Comment: @luchonacho, for me it works, replacing `anchor=west` at the `y label style` by `anchor=south,rotate=-90`.

Comment: @Jake Hi! I've been using this for quite a while. very helpful. But if I scale the figure (with `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=x]`) the labels are wrongly placed. Do you know how to keep the ratio of labels with the rest of the picture?

Comment: @luchonacho: You can add the `scale=x` key to the `axis` options instead of the `tikzpicture` options.